# SharePoint 365 javascript Rest API geting 403 on file upload

Tags: javascript, file-upload, php

I am tring to upload the big file to **SharePoint 365** using javascript but I **getting the 403**. In that I have used auth client library to generate the **access token and form Digest**.

Below is my code:

```
 'use strict';

    var appWebUrl, hostWebUrl;
    String.format = function () {
        var s = arguments[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i += 1) {
            var reg = new RegExp('\\{' + i + '\\}', 'gm');
            s = s.replace(reg, arguments[i + 1]);
        }
        return s;
    };

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        // Check for FileReader API (HTML5) support.
        if (!window.FileReader) {
            alert('This browser does not support the FileReader API.');
        }

        // Get the add-in web and host web URLs.

        appWebUrl = "https://mysite.sharepoint.com";
        hostWebUrl = "<?= $siteUrl ?>";
    });

// Upload the file.
// You can upload files up to 2 GB with the REST API.
    function uploadFile() {

        // Define the folder path for this example.
        var serverRelativeUrlToFolder = '/sites/sitename/AppCatalog/foldername/';

        // Get test values from the file input and text input page controls.
        // The display name must be unique every time you run the example.
        var fileInput = jQuery('#getFile');
        var newName = jQuery('#displayName').val();

        // Initiate method calls using jQuery promises.
        // Get the local file as an array buffer.
        var getFile = getFileBuffer();
        getFile.done(function (arrayBuffer) {

            // Add the file to the SharePoint folder.
            var addFile = addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer);
            addFile.done(function (file, status, xhr) {

                // Get the list item that corresponds to the uploaded file.
                var getItem = getListItem(file.d.ListItemAllFields.__deferred.uri);
                getItem.done(function (listItem, status, xhr) {

                    // Change the display name and title of the list item.
                    var changeItem = updateListItem(listItem.d.__metadata);
                    changeItem.done(function (data, status, xhr) {
                        alert('file uploaded and updated');
                    });
                    changeItem.fail(onError);
                });
                getItem.fail(onError);
            });
            addFile.fail(onError);
        });
        getFile.fail(onError);

        // Get the local file as an array buffer.
        function getFileBuffer() {
            var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function (e) {
                deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
            }
            reader.onerror = function (e) {
                deferred.reject(e.target.error);
            }
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput[0].files[0]);
            return deferred.promise();
        }

        // Add the file to the file collection in the Shared Documents folder.
        function addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer) {

            // Get the file name from the file input control on the page.
            var parts = fileInput[0].value.split('\\');
            var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

            // Construct the endpoint.
            var fileCollectionEndpoint = String.format(
                    "{0}/_api/sp.appcontextsite(@target)/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/files" +
                    "/add(overwrite=true, url='{2}')?@target='{3}'",
                    appWebUrl, serverRelativeUrlToFolder, fileName, hostWebUrl);


            // Send the request and return the response.
            // This call returns the SharePoint file.
            return jQuery.ajax({
                url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
                type: "POST",
                data: arrayBuffer,
                processData: false,
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "Authorization": "Bearer <?= $site->getSPAccessToken()?>",
                    "X-RequestDigest": "<?= $digest ?>",
                    "content-length": arrayBuffer.byteLength
                }
            });
        }

        // Get the list item that corresponds to the file by calling the file's ListItemAllFields property.
        function getListItem(fileListItemUri) {

            // Construct the endpoint.
            // The list item URI uses the host web, but the cross-domain call is sent to the
            // add-in web and specifies the host web as the context site.
            fileListItemUri = fileListItemUri.replace(hostWebUrl, '{0}');
            fileListItemUri = fileListItemUri.replace('_api/Web', '_api/sp.appcontextsite(@target)/web');

            var listItemAllFieldsEndpoint = String.format(fileListItemUri + "?@target='{1}'",
                    appWebUrl, hostWebUrl);

            // Send the request and return the response.
            return jQuery.ajax({
                url: listItemAllFieldsEndpoint,
                type: "GET",
                headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}
            });
        }

        // Change the display name and title of the list item.
        function updateListItem(itemMetadata) {

            // Construct the endpoint.
            // Specify the host web as the context site.
            var listItemUri = itemMetadata.uri.replace('_api/Web', '_api/sp.appcontextsite(@target)/web');
            var listItemEndpoint = String.format(listItemUri + "?@target='{0}'", hostWebUrl);

            // Define the list item changes. Use the FileLeafRef property to change the display name.
            // For simplicity, also use the name as the title.
            // The example gets the list item type from the item's metadata, but you can also get it from the
            // ListItemEntityTypeFullName property of the list.
            var body = String.format("{{'__metadata':{{'type':'{0}'}},'FileLeafRef':'{1}','Title':'{2}'}}",
                    itemMetadata.type, newName, newName);

            // Send the request and return the promise.
            // This call does not return response content from the server.
            return jQuery.ajax({
                url: listItemEndpoint,
                type: "POST",
                data: body,
                headers: {
                    "X-RequestDigest": "<?= $digest ?>",
                    "Authorization": "Bearer <?= $site->getSPAccessToken()?>",
                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "content-length": body.length,
                    "IF-MATCH": itemMetadata.etag,
                    "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
                }
            });
        }
    }

// Display error messages.
    function onError(error) {
        alert(error.responseText);
    }

// Get parameters from the query string.
// For production purposes you may want to use a library to handle the query string.
    function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
        var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&amp;");
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
            var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
            if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
                return singleParam[1];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue using below code

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://site.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<input id="getFile" type="file"/><br />
<input id="displayName" type="text" value="Enter a unique name" /><br />
<input id="addFileButton" type="button" value="Upload" onclick="uploadFile()"/>
<input type="hidden" value="" id="__REQUESTDIGEST">
    'use strict';

    var appWebUrl, hostWebUrl;
    String.format = function () {
        var s = arguments[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i += 1) {
            var reg = new RegExp('\\{' + i + '\\}', 'gm');
            s = s.replace(reg, arguments[i + 1]);
        }
        return s;
    };



    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var getFormDgst= function() {

        var req = {};
        req.url = "https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/contextinfo";
        req.method = "POST";
        req.body = "";
        req.headers = {
          "Authorization" : "Bearer <?= $site->getSPAccessToken()?>",
          "Accept" : "application/json; odata=verbose",
        };
        req.success = function(data) {
          //get context info from data.
          jQuery('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue)

        };
        req.failure = function(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {

        }
        jQuery.ajax(req);
      }

getFormDgst();
        // Check for FileReader API (HTML5) support.
        if (!window.FileReader) {
            alert('This browser does not support the FileReader API.');
        }

        // Get the add-in web and host web URLs.

        appWebUrl = "https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename";
        hostWebUrl = "<?= $siteUrl ?>";
    });

// Upload the file.
// You can upload files up to 2 GB with the REST API.
    function uploadFile() {

        // Define the folder path for this example.
        var serverRelativeUrlToFolder = 'AppCatalog/video/';

        // Get test values from the file input and text input page controls.
        // The display name must be unique every time you run the example.
        var fileInput = jQuery('#getFile');
        var newName = jQuery('#displayName').val();

        // Initiate method calls using jQuery promises.
        // Get the local file as an array buffer.
        var getFile = getFileBuffer();
        getFile.done(function (arrayBuffer) {

            // Add the file to the SharePoint folder.
            var addFile = addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer);
            addFile.done(function (file, status, xhr) {

                // Get the list item that corresponds to the uploaded file.
                var getItem = getListItem(file.d.ListItemAllFields.__deferred.uri);
                getItem.done(function (listItem, status, xhr) {

                    // Change the display name and title of the list item.
                    var changeItem = updateListItem(listItem.d.__metadata);
                    changeItem.done(function (data, status, xhr) {
                        alert('file uploaded and updated');
                    });
                    changeItem.fail(onError);
                });
                getItem.fail(onError);
            });
            addFile.fail(onError);
        });
        getFile.fail(onError);

        // Get the local file as an array buffer.
        function getFileBuffer() {
            var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function (e) {
                deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
            }
            reader.onerror = function (e) {
                deferred.reject(e.target.error);
            }
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput[0].files[0]);
            return deferred.promise();
        }

        // Add the file to the file collection in the Shared Documents folder.
        function addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer) {

            // Get the file name from the file input control on the page.
            var parts = fileInput[0].value.split('\\');
            var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

            // Construct the endpoint.
            var fileCollectionEndpoint = String.format(
                    "{0}/_api/sp.appcontextsite(@target)/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/files" +
                    "/add(overwrite=true, url='{2}')?@target='{3}'",
                    appWebUrl, serverRelativeUrlToFolder, fileName, hostWebUrl);


            // Send the request and return the response.
            // This call returns the SharePoint file.
            return jQuery.ajax({
                url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
                type: "POST",
                data: arrayBuffer,
                processData: false,
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "Authorization": "Bearer <?= $site->getSPAccessToken()?>",
                    "X-RequestDigest": jQuery('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(),
                    "content-length": arrayBuffer.byteLength
                }
            });
        }

        // Get the list item that corresponds to the file by calling the file's ListItemAllFields property.
        function getListItem(fileListItemUri) {

            // Construct the endpoint.
            // The list item URI uses the host web, but the cross-domain call is sent to the
            // add-in web and specifies the host web as the context site.
            fileListItemUri = fileListItemUri.replace(hostWebUrl, '{0}');
            fileListItemUri = fileListItemUri.replace('_api/Web', '_api/sp.appcontextsite(@target)/web');

            var listItemAllFieldsEndpoint = String.format(fileListItemUri + "?@target='{1}'",
                    appWebUrl, hostWebUrl);

            // Send the request and return the response.
            return jQuery.ajax({
                url: listItemAllFieldsEndpoint,
                type: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "Authorization": "Bearer <?= $site->getSPAccessToken()?>",
                }
            });
        }

        // Change the display name and title of the list item.
        function updateListItem(itemMetadata) {

            // Construct the endpoint.
            // Specify the host web as the context site.
            var listItemUri = itemMetadata.uri.replace('_api/Web', '_api/sp.appcontextsite(@target)/web');
            var listItemEndpoint = String.format(listItemUri + "?@target='{0}'", hostWebUrl);

            // Define the list item changes. Use the FileLeafRef property to change the display name.
            // For simplicity, also use the name as the title.
            // The example gets the list item type from the item's metadata, but you can also get it from the
            // ListItemEntityTypeFullName property of the list.
            var body = String.format("{{'__metadata':{{'type':'{0}'}},'FileLeafRef':'{1}','Title':'{2}'}}",
                    itemMetadata.type, newName, newName);

            // Send the request and return the promise.
            // This call does not return response content from the server.
            return jQuery.ajax({
                url: listItemEndpoint,
                type: "POST",
                data: body,
                headers: {
                    "X-RequestDigest": jQuery('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(),
                    "Authorization": "Bearer <?= $site->getSPAccessToken()?>",
                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "content-length": body.length,
                    "IF-MATCH": itemMetadata.etag,
                    "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
                }
            });
        }
    }

// Display error messages.
    function onError(error) {
        alert(error.responseText);
    }

// Get parameters from the query string.
// For production purposes you may want to use a library to handle the query string.
    function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
        var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&amp;");
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
            var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
            if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
                return singleParam[1];
        }
    }

</script>
```